# Any way to check if data exist in database during an SQL bulk copy

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I'm copying some data from one SQL Server database to another SQL Server database.

That works fine, what I need is to check if some data already exists, then not copy it. How can I do that? Any suggestions?

```
string Source = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db1"].ConnectionString;
string Destination = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Db2"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection sourceCon = new SqlConnection(Source))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Id],[Client] FROM [Db1].[dbo].[Client]", sourceCon);
    sourceCon.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        using (SqlConnection destCon = new SqlConnection(Destination))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(destCon))
            {
                    bc.DestinationTableName = "Clients";
                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "ClientId");
                    bc.ColumnMappings.Add("Client", "Client");
                    destCon.Open();

                    bc.WriteToServer(rdr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Insert in Temp table then use a merge query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do what you're after would be to bulk-copy into a *staging* table (a separate table with similar layout), and then perform a conditional insert from the staging table into the real table.

You could also do something similar using a table-valued-parameter instead of `SqlBulkCopy`, and treat the table-valued-parameter as the staging table.

Comment: We implemented such a solution, and also perform mass updates this way. (update instead of insert). The execution time of this strategy was lowest of any other way we tried by a large margin / factor

Comment: I am not sure this does not say more about your implementation. Merge or delete an reload (with partitioning) are generarally the fastest ways. If you know how to properly use sql server. I.e. your load changed - you did use Merge, right?

Comment: Your comment about how to use sql was uncalled for. Our use case does not have deletion in it. We do not use the merge statement as the system was pre merge in sql

Answer (score 0):

You could make a database link from source db to destination, and run a query to work out which rows would need to transit, but be careful not to drag too much data over the link as it could make the process slow- realistically you only need the. Columns you will use to determine whether a row in the source equals a row in the dest

Typically though it's easier to bulk copy all the data into a temporary table at the destination then use a merge or insert-leftjoin to only insert some data from temporary table to real table

Here's an example of how to insert only some rows that don't already exist:

```
INSERT INTO real(column1,column2...)
SELECT temp.column1,temp.column2... FROM
  temp 
  LEFT JOIN real ON real.ID = temp.ID
WHERE 
  real.ID IS NULL
```

In c# terms it would look like:

```
  new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO real(column1,column2...)
SELECT temp.column1,temp.column2... FROM
  temp 
  LEFT JOIN real ON real.ID = temp.ID
WHERE 
  real.ID IS NULL", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You need to run this using a `conn` connected to your destination database

Comment: Thanks you. But can you tell me how to do that in my code? :)

Comment: I'll add it, but it's a single line of c# that I'm sure you already know.. I don't know your column names so there will still be some work for you to do

Answer (score 0):

Copy all tables from your source database to your destination database as temp tables, then run SQL to add the missing record from the temp table to the destination table. The final step to delete the temp tables.

hope that will work for you.